# Como funciona utilizar um vector do tipo struct ? (C++)

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados, vector

Eu gostaria de ajuda para entender como funciona declarar um vector do tipo struct. No exemplo do código abaixo eu crio a struct configcarros e gostaria de criar um vector do tipo desta estrutura e posteriormente acessar num_car e tempodevolta inserindo valores dentro do vector.

```
    struct configcarros{

        int num_car, tempodevolta;

    };

    int main(){

        int C,V, tempo;
        struct configcarros cars_ORD;
        cin >> C >> V;
        vector<struct configcarros> cars(C);

    }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender isso ? Não tô encontrando muita coisa pesquisando sobre vectors do tipo struct.

Comment: não seria apenas `vector <configcarros> cars`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Começo por dizer que, assim como o @RicardoPontual indicou nos comentários, em C++ não precisa de incluir a palavra `struct` na utilização da estrutura. Para além disso, sendo o `<vector>` algo com tamanho dinâmico pode cortar a inicialização que tem, e simplificar a declaração deixando apenas:

```
vector<configcarros> cars;
```

### Inserir estruturas no `<vector>`

Para inserir estruturas no vetor, pode criar a estrutura em si, definir os seus valores e adicionar através do método [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

```
configcarros c1; //criar objeto da estrutura
c1.num_car = 1; //definir o valor para num_car
c1.tempodevolta = 30; //definir o valor para tempodevolta

cars.push_back(c1); //adicionar ao vetor
```

Pode até utilizar uma inicialização mais direta fazendo:

```
configcarros c2{2, 35}; //inicializar logo com os 2 valores
cars.push_back(c2);
```

Ou fazer tudo *inline*:

```
cars.push_back(configcarros{5,15});
```

### Ler as estruturas guardadas no `<vector>`

A leitura é feita como se fosse um array normal utilizando `[` e `]`, colocando a posição que quer aceder no meio. Assim para aceder ao campo `num_car` da primeira posição do vetor, a posição `0`, faria:

```
cars[0].num_car
```

Para mostrar os dois valores do primeiro carro na consola pode fazer:

```
cout<<cars[0].num_car<<" "<<cars[0].tempodevolta;
```

Quando precisa de percorrer todos deve utilizar um laço/ciclo, no qual o `for` costuma ser o mais apropriado. Existem muitas formas diferentes de fazer este `for` mas irei exemplificar a mais simples e clássica:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
    cout<<cars[i].num_car<<" "<<cars[i].tempodevolta<<endl;
}
```

É importante de notar que o `for` baseia-se no tamanho de vetor, chamando o método [`size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) do mesmo. Para que não ficasse tudo na mesma linha no ecrã adicionei um `endl` no fim do `cout`

[Exemplo de tudo isto no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ozg1Nt)

Documentação

- [`push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)
- [`size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/)